# How to force flex columns to stay on the same line if container 'flex-wrap' is set to 'wrap'

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create the layout with one row and two columns inside one flex container. Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/73574emn/1/ .

What I want is to make the row always stay above columns and both columns to stay on the same line. Obviously, now if I make the window too small then column3 will move down under the column2 because `flex-wrap` property is set to `wrap` (because I need row and columns to be on separate lines).

I suppose that I can wrap row in one flex container and both columns in another, **but** I want to know if there are any ways to do it while they are in the same container, and if yes then how it works. Maybe I can do something with width or min-width?

```css
*
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
}

.column1 {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.column2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <div class='row'>Hithis is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence </div>
    <div class='column1'>Hellothis is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence </div>
    <div class='column2'>Hello 2this is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A flex item's `min-width` defaults to `auto`, and as such it will not allow the element to be smaller than its content.

Add `overflow: hidden` to the side-by-side columns and they will not wrap

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73574emn/389/)

```
.flex > div
{
   flex: 1 0 50%;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

An alternative is to use `min-width: 0`, though that might make the content overflow

```
.flex > div
{
   flex: 1 0 50%;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 10px;
   min-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you! both of these approaches work. can you please explain why does it work like this or give any links where I can read about it?

Comment: @alinaish The `min-width` defaults to `auto`, and as such it will not allow the element to be smaller than the content. The `min-width: 0` or `overflow: hidden` solves that

Answer (score 4):

Simply remove flex-basis value

Change

```
flex:1 0 50%;
```

To

```
flex:1 0;
```

Then Add Width to column

```
width:50%;
```

Here is the example:

```css
*
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
}

.column1 {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width:50%;
}

.column2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <div class='row'>Hithis is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence </div>
    <div class='column1'>Hellothis is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence </div>
    <div class='column2'>Hello 2this is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence this is a long test sentence </div>
</div>
```